# Pandas is not creating extra (duplicated) index after groupby and nlargest if all the values are the same

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get a column value that represents most of a grouped rows. Let's say I have the following data frame.

```
df = pd.read_csv("test2.csv")
print(df)

     loc address  mod1  mod2  mod3
0      A   addr1     0     0     0
1      A   addr1     0     1     0
2      A   addr1     0     3     0
3      A   addr1     0     3     0
4      A   addr1     0     3     2
5      A   addr1     0     3     2
6      A   addr1     0     3     2
7      A   addr2     0     0     0
8      A   addr2     0     1     0
9      A   addr2     0     1     0
10     B   addr1     0     0     0
11     B   addr1     0     0     2
12     B   addr1     0     1     1
13     B   addr1     0     0     2
14     B   addr1     0     2     2
15     B   addr2     0     1     0
16     C   addr1     0     1     0
17     C   addr1     0     0     1
```

The value that represents "mod2" the most for "A addr1" group is 3 and "A addr2" group is 1.
To achieve that, I use the following code:

```
a = df.groupby(['loc','address'])['mod2'] \
  .value_counts() \
  .groupby(['loc','address']) \
  .nlargest(1) \
  .reset_index(level=[0,1],drop=True) \
  .rename_axis(['loc','address','mod2']) \
  .reset_index(name='counts')[['loc','address','mod2']]
print(a)

  loc address  mod2
0   A   addr1     3
1   A   addr2     1
2   B   addr1     0
3   B   addr2     1
4   C   addr1     0
```

However, this fails with a message "ValueError: Length of new names must be 1, got 3" when the column value is the same for all groups. Please see "mod1" column in the first dataframe printed above. I used the same code, only changed the column "mod2" to "mod1".

```
c = df.groupby(['loc','address'])['mod1'] \
      .value_counts() \
      .groupby(['loc','address']) \
      .nlargest(1) \
      .reset_index(level=[0,1],drop=True) \
      .rename_axis(['loc','address','mod1']) \
      .reset_index(name='counts')[['loc','address','mod1']]
print(c)
```

The failure happens at "rename_axis" portion of the code. "Groupby" for value_counts adds "loc" and "address" as indexes and "groupby" for nlargest duplicates these indexes for "mod2". However, "groupby" for nlargest for "mod1" doesn't duplicate the same index because the output of the first and second "groupby" are the same due to all of the rows having zero value for this column. "reset_index" drops the first two levels for both causing the first example to have "loc","address" and "mod2" columns and the second example to have have only "mod1" column.

Is there any way to avoid this? Or is there anyway to simplify what I am trying to achieve?

Edit: Expected outcome should be as follows:

```
  loc address  mod1 
0   A   addr1     0
1   A   addr2     0
2   B   addr1     0
3   B   addr2     0
4   C   addr1     0
```

Then I will join them to have the following output:

```
  loc address  mod1 mod2 
0   A   addr1     0    3
1   A   addr2     0    1
2   B   addr1     0    0
3   B   addr2     0    1
4   C   addr1     0    0
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the expected outcome, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `nlargest(1)` by `head(1)` and keep only your index as a dataframe:

For `mod1`:

```
>>> df.groupby(['loc','address'])['mod1'] \
      .value_counts() \
      .groupby(['loc','address']) \
      .head(1) \
      .index.to_frame() \
      .reset_index(drop=True)

  loc address  mod1
0   A   addr1     0
1   A   addr2     0
2   B   addr1     0
3   B   addr2     0
4   C   addr1     0
```

For `mod2`:

```
  loc address  mod2
0   A   addr1     3
1   A   addr2     1
2   B   addr1     0
3   B   addr2     1
4   C   addr1     0
```

For `mod3`:

```
  loc address  mod3
0   A   addr1     0
1   A   addr2     0
2   B   addr1     2
3   B   addr2     0
4   C   addr1     0
```

Comment: I did. Thanks for the link @corralien

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
new_df = df[['loc', 'address']].drop_duplicates()
for col in df.drop(['loc', 'address'], axis=1).columns:
    new_df = new_df.merge(df[['loc', 'address', col]].value_counts().reset_index().sort_values(col).drop_duplicates(['loc', 'address'], keep='last'))
```

My version of `pandas` doesn't have `value_counts` function on `df` (it's from 1.1.0) so I did it from my mind. Otherwise you will need to change the function to a longer `groupby` with `count`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, it didn't generate the result that i wanted. I will play with this a little bit more by combining it with Corralien's answer.

Comment: @goober Yep. Instead of `.sort_values(col)` it should be sorted by the name of the `series` that was generated in the `value_counts` and not `col`. This is the downside of not being able to actually run the code :)